# TextBlock Text Binding an ObservableCollection.Count property

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox

I have a `ObservableCollection<Sportisti>` that starts out with 0 elements (but is initialized to a new object at the creation of the window). I wanted to bind the `Count` property to a `TextBox`. Unfortunately, this causes my application to crash whenever I try to open the window in question.

Now, since I have a `ListView` on the same page, successfully showing the elements of the collection in question, I thought I could simply extract the number of rows from there, but that also lead to a crash.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=lvTabela, Path=Items.Count}"
         Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,3,60,3"
         DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Note that in the .xaml file I can see the content of the TextBox is 0.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: "this causes my application to crash" "Any idea why this is happening?" Your debugger already knows this, don't expect anyone here to do your debuggers work *again*. Post the findings, maybe somebody will help you with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My mistake, I forgot to add the `Mode=OneWay` to the binding. The problem was that, even though the TextBox wasn't editable, the system recognized this as a potential way of changing the ListView.ItemCount attribute, which is read-only.

Comment: Don't forget, it's OK to answer your own question. Mark it as answered so other developers know that is a solved problem. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: Initialize your collection to empty objects in your code when the the list initializes. 
This may help you.